# Отправка POST запроса на сторонний сервер

Tags: javascript, jquery

Необходимо оправить JSON объект на сторонний сервер и получить от него ответ. Аутентификация пользователя на сервере организована с помощью токена.

Отправляю следующим образом:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('POST', 'https://example.com/api/v1/', true);
xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json; charset=utf-8');
xhr.setRequestHeader('Authentication', 'TOKEN_CODE');
xhr.send(jsonArr);
xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
        if(xhr.status == 200) {
            console.log('response:', xhr.responseText)
        } else {
            console.log('error:', xhr.responseText)
        }
    }
};
```

Но в консоли получаю 400 (Bad Request).

Также пробовал отправить с помощью jQuery:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "https://example.com/api/v1/",
    type: 'POST',
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    crossDomain: true,
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    data: JSON.stringify(jsonArr),
    headers: {'Authentication': 'TOKEN_CODE'},
    error : function(error) {
        console.log('ERROR:', error);
    },
    success: function(data) {
        console.log('SUCCESS:', data);
    }
});
```

При таком варианте в консоли ошибка 414 (Request-URI Too Large)

Собственно вопрос, как правильно выполнить запрос?

Comment: Ошибка 414 в данном случае означает, что ваш сторонний сервер не может обработать запрос, т.к. URI слишком большой. Вот тут подробнее https://ruhighload.com/414+request+uri+too+large

То есть, ваш клиентский код работает корректно

Comment: Кросс доменные запросы и все что с ними связано. И да - так просто это не заведется